# How can I use git to automatically keep all Laravel sites in production updated?

Tags: php, git, laravel, laravel-4, bitbucket

I have a site skeleton built on Laravel 4 in a private git repo on Bitbucket. Our very small team each has their own local development copy, and there's also a version of the site on a development environment which we use to display things to clients. In addition, there's a branded production version of the site open to the public, and we're in the process of setting up two or three new sites based on the same git repo.

Now, installing new sites is ridiculously easy... but I don't really know how to keep them all properly updated except for logging in and pulling manually every time we make an update. Ideally, I would like to be able to specify that a commit to the repo triggers all of the production environments to pull the new version.

Is this something which can be easily done, and if so, how? We're expecting to release more and more sites based on the template, and I would prefer to set it up correctly from the beginning, rather than throwing something together after it's become a problem.

Comment: I wouldn't.  Git isn't meant for deployment, it's meant for version control.  Use the right tool for the right job.  Besides, what if somebody commits broken code?

Comment: I'd listen to @GordonM however you could try to look into a webhook like https://github.com/Coppertino/github-webhook and git hooks in general http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: You can use a server-side hook to deploy on push. You might as well checkout continuous integration systems like Jenkins to see if they fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @GordonM - point taken. If it's rightly considered a security risk, then I will pursue a smarter solution instead, or just do it manually.

Comment: Thanks @OneOfOne and Dikei too - good comments!

Comment: You're welcome, one more idea too, have a pre-commit hook on the dev side to make sure nothing is broken before committing, that way you wouldn't push a broken commit.

Comment: That does sound like a very good idea.

Comment: I prefer having a very different local environment and a staging server which looks exactly the same as production. What I do is to push to a staging branch, let Deeployer take care of deployment to the staging machine, run my tests, then push the same commit to a production branch.

Comment: That makes sense @AntonioCarlosRibeiro. I'll give it a thought for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tools available to help you with that, like Capistrano, but I could not find one, written in PHP, which was able to do it via github/bitbucket hooks, so I built a package to help me with that: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/deeployer.

It uses [Laravel Envoy](https://github.com/laravel/envoy) to provide some scripting to your deployment process.

Using Envoy make it easy to run your tasks manually in the command line by doing:

```
cd <your deployer directory>

envoy run <task name>
```

An example would be:

```
envoy run https://github.com/antonioribeiro/deeployer:master
```

Comment: That looks very interesting - thanks! I'll take a thorough look, have an upvote in the meantime. :)

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro, can i manually(from command line) trigger the deployment instead of web hooks?